# How to keep track of items that each user's viewed

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I have lists of `product` and `categories` and need to know if each user has viewed them, also total number of `products` for each `category` that have been viewed by each user.

In short, I need to keep lists of

- Products that each user viewed (Once a user viewed a product's profile it will be added to this list)
- Categories that each user viewed (Once a user viewed a category's profile it will be added to this list)
- Number of products in each category that have been    viewed by
  each user?

I've added two member variables to `Client` class as following. 
I am not sure if it is correct or not, secondly I do not know how to keep a counter for all viewed products of each category per user. (I know I can retrieve it using (COUNT) function of database but I am wondering if there is any other efficient way rather than sending this request to database).

**Client:**

```
@Entity
public class Client {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  private long id;

  @OneToOne
  private List<Product> viewedProducts = new ArrayList<Product>(); //keep list of viewed products

  @OneToOne
  private List<Category> viewedCategories = new ArrayList<Category>(); //keep list of viewed categories

  ....
}
```

**Product**

```
@Entity
public class Product {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  private long id;

  @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  private Category category;

  .... 
}
```

**Category**

```
@Entity
public class Category {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  private long id;

  ....
}
```

Comment: So other way means u have to add the logic for that on each click of categaory and product .Like u can create a map in which the category name will e the key and the list of products will be the value

Comment: I do not get you, how to define the variable members then?

Comment: currently i think u are saving the values of the Client instances to the db for each click so if it is not required for future then u can make temporary list and can use

Comment: @Deepak I need to keep all the lists, list of viewed products, viewed categories and number of viewed products in each category (Per user)

Comment: Is this auditing or sales?

Comment: @flup it is kina sales

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion is to keep those member variables that you have at the moment, and add the following to your class

```
   @OneToMany
   private List<ViewedProductsPerCategory> = 
                                    new ArrayList<ViewedProductsPerCategory>();
```

in that class you should have

```
@Entity
public class ViewedProductsPerCategory {
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue
   long id;

   @OneToMany 
   Category category;

   long CatCounter;

   long ProCounter;

   getters and setters;
}
```

BUT make sure to keep the counters in cookie rather than calling database every time that user visit a product or category. After user's logged out add the numbers in cookie to the respective counters in database.

Issue: Be aware that user may delete the cookie before logging out, although it is very rare as most users do not delete their cookies while are logged in to avoid being logged out.

Answer (score 1):

First, you should use `@ManyToMany` annotation for `viewedProducts` and `viewedCategories`. Second, how many products are there? If hundreds or thousands, you may need to do paging through viewed products, or fetch some of them by context or whatever else. When you have collection of `viewedProducts`, you deal with all the viewed products loaded into memory from database which leads to performance loss. So you would better to create objects like these:

```
@Entity public ViewedProduct {
    @Id private Integer id;
    @ManyToOne
    private Client customer;
    @ManyToOne
    private Product product;

    ViewedProduct(Client customer, Product product) {
        this.customer = customer;
        this.product = product;
    }

    public Client getCustomer() {
         return customer;
    }

    public Product getProduct() {
         return product;
    }
}

@Entity public ViewedCategory {
    @Id private Integer id;
    @ManyToOne
    private Client customer;
    @ManyToOne
    private Category category;
    @Basic
    private int viewedProductCount;

    ViewedCategory(Client customer, Category category) {
        this.customer = customer;
        this.category = category;
    }

    void incrementViewedProducts() {
        viewedProductCount++;
    }

    public Client getCustomer() {
        return customer;
    }

    public Product getProduct() {
        return product;
    }
}

public class ProductViewService {
     private ViewedProductRepository viewedProductRepository;
     private ViewedCategoryRepository viewedCategoryRepository;

     public ProductViewService(ViewedProductRepository viewedProductRepository,
             ViewedCategoryRepository viewedCategoryRepository) {
         this.viewedProductRepository = viewedProductRepository;
         this.viewedCategoryRepository = viewedCategoryRepository;
     }

     public void viewProductByCustomer(Client customer, Product product) {
         ViewedProduct vp = viewedProductRepository.find(customer, product);
         if (vp == null) {
             vp = new ViewedProduct(customer, product);
             viewedProductRepository.add(vp);
             ViewedCategory vc = viewedCategoryRepository.find(customer, product.getCategory());
             if (vc == null) {
                 vc = new ViewedCategory(customer, product.getCategory());
                 viewedCategoryRepository.add(vc);
             }
             vc.incrementViewedProducts();
         }
     }
}

public interface ViewedProductRepository {
    ViewedProduct find(Client customer, Product product);
    void add(VIewedProduct product);
    List<Product> getRecentlyViewedProducts(Client customer, int limit);
    // etc
}

public class PersistentViewedProductRepository implements ViewedProductRepository {
    private EntityManager em;

    public List<Product> getRecentlyViewedProducts(Client customer, int limit) {
        return em.createQuery(
                "select vp.product " + 
                "from ViewedProduct vp " +
                "where vp.customer = :customer " +
                "order by vp.id desc", Product.class)
                .setMaxResults(limit)
                .getResultList();
    }

    // etc
}
```

for counting products you should decide, whether denormalization is really needed. If it is really doesn't, you can throw away `viewedProductCount` and use JPQL queries to get this quantity as needed.

Comment: You've suggested me to use @ ManyToMany but in the solution code I could not find any such annotation. is that a typo? what does @ Basic do? Are you agree with J888 that the counter should be kept in cookie before being added to the database value ?

Comment: Read carefully. I said, that in your case `@ManyToMany` would be solution. But further I noticed that your approach leads to performance loss and suggested another approach, without `@ManyToMany` at all. [`@Basic`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Basic.html) can be ommited here.

Comment: I disagree with @J888 that counter should be kept in cookie, as cookies are always being sent to server and with many products it leads to growing network traffic. Better use [HTML 5 Storage](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/features/storage). But keep in mind, that significant number of people are using browsers without support of Storage.

Comment: So I suppose should use cookies, in this way I would sacrifice network traffic for supporting all users. As it would be disappointing to have a number of people who can not use the application becausse are using a not supporting device or browser. Do you agree?

Comment: @AlexCartio1, you may combine approaches. For example, when number of products grows large, you can clear user's cookies and store products in the database. Or, if available, in HTML 5 storage. And think about another thing: cookies are kept in browser, so if user logs in from another device, he won't get products he already visited.

Comment: Problem is that lets say user visit product1 of categoryA and then decided to visit product2 of categoryB in that case do I need to keep the id of all products in a single cookie? a list of ids in cookie? is  there any limitation for length of cookie?

Comment: @AlexCartio1, Browsers have limitations on the number of cookies and a single cookie's length. By RFC the guaranteed limit is at 20 cookies per domain and at least 4096 bytes length of one cookie. So you better to store some part of ids in one cookie, another part in another cookie, etc.

Answer (score 0):

If the number of views for products by customer is not actually required by your application, but instead is a metric needed by the business/marketing to gauge customer interest, then I don't think you should put that logic into your application.  There are several non intrusive ways you can provide that information without bugging down your app with constant DB writes on every page view.

Depending on how your **logging** is done, you could setup access logging like so:

```
2013-12-03 17:31:44 user:username@example.com INFO  com.acme.web.interceptors.AccessLogInterceptor  - URL [/product/1234]
```

Then using log analyzer tools (I user Heroku which has Logentries add-on) to gather your business intelligence information.  This also avoid you having to write code to display/export the data, it's all already built into the tool.

Another option is using **Google Analytics**, it gives you much more detailed information about user's browsing patterns, drop off rates, etc.

Answer (score 0):

It would make things simpler if we add to the domain model a couple of entities corresponding to some concepts that could be missing from the model.

If this a marketing/sales domain it would be better to add some new [entities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity) such as ProductViewEvent and CategoryViewEvent for the first  two points, that point to Category and Product and contain all the properties of the view event.

The Product and the Category themselves do not need to reference the event entities, it would be a unidirectional relation from the event entity to Category/Product.

Depending on the domain these event entities could even become [value objects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Value_object), are two view events completely interchangeable from a domain point-of-view?

For the third point, add a new [service](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service_%28systems_architecture%29) StatisticsService that gives the grouped totals you need on a service method.

For the running totals, if it causes a performance problem running the COUNTs on the database, it's always possible to add an attribute with the running total of views for Category/Product.

But update these running totals with batch update queries at the service layer of the form *update total = total + difference where ...* to ensure the totals are kept consistence from a database transaction point of view.

It's better to not use this optimization unless it's necessary, this depends on the expected volume of views. do you have an idea if it's on the thousands, millions range?